# Error: Module not specified, but there is no field to enter module

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-ee-6

I have just created a new Java EE project in IntelliJ and I tried to create a new run configuration. The run configuration fails to run because I did not specify a module, but there is no field to specify a module as seen in a picture:
[image]

In the older project, however, there is a field to add a new module. I don't understand why it is not visible in the new module.

[image]

I believe this only started to occur during the last update. Any help would be appreciated.

Update:
I looked into workspace.xml, here's a difference between two configurations:

```
<configuration name="Test" type="Application" factoryName="Application" activateToolWindowBeforeRun="false">
  <option name="ALTERNATIVE_JRE_PATH" value="14" />
  <option name="ALTERNATIVE_JRE_PATH_ENABLED" value="true" />
  <option name="MAIN_CLASS_NAME" value="com.kumuluz.ee.EeApplication" />
  <method v="2">
    <option name="Make" enabled="true" />
  </method>
</configuration>
```

And the other one

```
<configuration name="SledilnikObiskovalcev" type="Application" factoryName="Application">
  <option name="MAIN_CLASS_NAME" value="com.kumuluz.ee.EeApplication" />
  <module name="api" />
  <method v="2">
    <option name="Make" enabled="true" />
  </method>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please click on "Modify options" and select "Use classpath of module".

Answer (score 0):

Working workaround is to edit Workspace.xml in folder .idea and add the following line into the configuration manually:

```
<module name="api" />
```

No idea why this issue happens.